# Can temperature dissipate inside a perfect insulator?

Tags: energy, temperature

This is my first post to this forum, and being that my primary education is not related to physics I apologize in advance.

I was brainstorming how I could code a scenario searching for equilibrium temperature where there is a permeable barrier between two varying temperatures.    I was toying with how I might accomplish this when it occurred to me that I don't know how heat can be lost. I have an understanding of the laws of entropy, but were I to have a perfect insulator, is it at all possible that there could be temperature fluctuations inside the insulated area? I know this is an open ended question.  Just curious if there are methods through which heat dissipate. Thanks for entertaining my curiosity!!!

Answer (score 0):

If the definition of "perfect insulator" is a material through which no heat can travel, then if you put an object like a lump of iron at, say 200 degrees Centigrade inside a container made of "perfect insulator", then the iron would still be at 200 degrees C in a million years.  There would be no temperature fluctuations inside the insulator, because temperature fluctuations would require flow of heat.

Of course there is no such thing as a perfect insulator, though there are insulating materials that allegedly could keep an ice cube frozen in orbit for at least a year.

Comment: A bare ice cube in orbit will also stay frozen for at least a year, as long as the orbit is high enough and you neglect sublimation, so I'm not sure that the marketers actually said anything there.

Comment: Thank you both! Love your inputs and appreciate the fun facts :D

Answer (score 0):

To add to S. McGrew's answer, if you separated the volume inside this perfect insulating container into two compartments of different temperature, with a permeable (not perfect insulator) barrier, as you state in the question, the two compartments will indeed reach equilibrium eventually. So if that's what you mean by "temperature fluctuation" then yes, no problem.

Comment: Alright. Thanks! I had that suspicion.  Since I've never studied this I figured I would poll this community rather than try to determine it myself.  I wasn't sure if the energy in the heat could manifest itself in some other form, or if heat was the ultimate indicator of energy.  Is that true?  Are there applicable ways to convert heat to other types of energy provided the container doesn't do work on the environment? I know you can turn heat into work. Just not sure if heat can change into other things? Lol I am not very smart